# Leaving IdentityServer page in Angular SPA ASP.NET Core app - reloads the app

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, security, identityserver4

I have ASP.NET Core Angular SPA app with IdentityServer 4.

Every time I go into Identity pages (eg Manage Account) and then I go back to my app (eg by clicking the Home link or Back button) the website reloads.

<s>Is it expected?</s> Can I configure this behaviour to be different?

**EDIT:** *it seems happening by design. I created quick test app and it behaves the same*

Comment: Are you visiting the Identity Pages and the angular app in the same browser tab?

Comment: yes............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently this is done by design as more secure approach. Found it here: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/

> A separately hosted login page is an improvement security-wise because this way the password is never directly handled by our application code in the first place.